# Could not identify the VM error while trying to Generate JAXB classes from xsd schema

Tags: java, android, jaxb

I am trying to generate JAXB classes from xsd schema in my android project. When i right click and give Generate JAXB Classes on schema file in the project folder, New JAXB Classes from schema wizard opens up. There I gave package path and ticked "Treat input as XML Schema". Before finish, it showed Configure JAXB compiler vendor extension. I gave class path of java jdk and gave Finish. But after finish, I get an error as "Could not identify the VM". 
I cannot figure out the exact cause of this error.
I am using Eclipse Kepler with ADT installed for android applications. Looking for solution to my problem.

Comment: I dont think android supports JAXB yet.

Comment: @Peshal : yes Peshal.. i need to find alternate ways of marshalling and unmarshalling objects in android.